# Update Select Join with NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have two Tables STR_IndentDetail and PUR_POIndent

STR_IndentDetail:

```
   IndentID   ItemID    POQty     D1      D2       D3        RD
  ---------   -------  ------    ----     ---     ---        ---
    2            1       NULL     10       20      30        NULL
    2            6       NULL     20       40      60        45
```

PUR_POIndent:

```
   POID        IndentID      ItemID     Quantity     D1     D2       D3        RD
  ------      ----------     ------    ----------   ----    ---      ---       ---
    2            2             1           55         10     20      30        NULL
    2            2             6           100        20     40      60         45
```

I want to Update STR_IndentDetail table POQty with PUR_POIndent table Quantity.
I have written two Update Statement based on INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER. But both the Queries Update only one row which has values in the Columns D1, D2, D3 and RD.
The row which contains the Column RD with NULL value is not getting UPDATE. How to write the Update Statement for this case. Below are my two Update Statements.

Based On Inner Join:

```
     UPDATE STR_IndentDetail
                SET
                    POQty = PUR_POIndent.Quantity
                FROM
                    PUR_POIndent
                WHERE
                    PUR_POIndent.IndentID           = STR_IndentDetail.IndentID AND
                    PUR_POIndent.ItemID             = STR_IndentDetail.ItemID   AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D1                 = STR_IndentDetail.D1       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D2                 = STR_IndentDetail.D2       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D3                 = STR_IndentDetail.D3       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.RD = STR_IndentDetail.RD 
                    AND PUR_POIndent.POID = 2
```

Based On Left Join:

```
 UPDATE STR_IndentDetail
                SET
                    POQty = PUR_POIndent.Quantity       
                FROM
                    STR_IndentDetail LEFT OUTER JOIN PUR_POIndent ON
                    PUR_POIndent.IndentID           = STR_IndentDetail.IndentID AND
                    PUR_POIndent.ItemID             = STR_IndentDetail.ItemID   AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D1                 = STR_IndentDetail.D1       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D2                 = STR_IndentDetail.D2       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.D3                 = STR_IndentDetail.D3       AND
                    PUR_POIndent.RD = STR_IndentDetail.RD        WHERE 
                        PUR_POIndent.POID = 2
```

Both the Queries ignores the row whose RD value is NULL.
I want to update both the rows. How to do this? Any Suggestions please.

Comment: but if more than 1 rows of null value then how do you compare the value of RD. that will give you wrong information.

Comment: PUR_POIndent table is derived from STR_IndentDetail. So PUR_POIndent table contains same records as STR_IndentDetail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare `NULL` values with `=`. Change the condition to use [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and pass a value that isn't present in your table.

**example**

```
ISNULL(PUR_POIndent.RD, -999) = ISNULL(STR_IndentDetail.RD, -999)
```

**[NULL Comparison Search Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270.aspx)**

> Care must be taken when comparing null
>   values. The behavior of the comparison
>   depends on the setting of the SET
>   ANSI_NULLS option.
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a
>   comparison in which one or more of the
>   expressions is NULL does not yield
>   either TRUE or FALSE; it yields
>   UNKNOWN. This is because a value that
>   is unknown cannot be compared
>   logically against any other value.
>   This occurs if either an expression is
>   compared to the literal NULL, or if
>   two expressions are compared and one
>   of them evaluates to NULL. For
>   example, the following comparison
>   always yields UNKNOWN when ANSI_NULLS
>   is ON:

Answer (score 1):

or

```
PUR_POIndent.RD=STR_IndentDetail.RD OR 
(PUR_POIndent.RD IS NULL AND STR_IndentDetail.RD IS NULL)
```